# How to set App bar component without iconElementLeft?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to use app bar component without left icon.

I tried to ignore the iconElementLeft property but it doesn't work and
the icon appears yet.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

const AppBar = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
  />
);

export default AppBar;
```

Is there a way to remove the left icon?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set `showMenuIconButton` to `false`.

```
<AppBar
    title="Title"
    showMenuIconButton={false}/>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyLye7jn/3/)

Comment: Do you know how to delete the h1 tag in AppBar? It is messing my css